# I am developing a wordpress theme and there is a warning. How to resolve this

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Warning is "*Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*"

```
<?php
    $tags = get_the_tags();
    foreach($tags as $tag):?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id);?>" class="badge badge-success">
            <?php echo $tag->name;?>
        </a>

    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Check whether tags is an array before trying to loop over it

Comment: try debugging `$tags`. `var_dump($tags)` will show you the value of it. My wordpress isn't the best, but in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) it looks like you are missing the parameters `$post_id` (or you are in `The loop`)

Comment: Where is this code actually going? Can you provide some more context.

Comment: this is in the theme directory section-blogcontent.php file

Comment: oh found it, the thing i didnt have any tags in my test post so it doesn't get the tag instead

Answer (score 1):

Check if your $tags variable is an actual array of elements before trying to loop through it all!..

ie:

```
<?php
$tags = get_the_tags(array('hide_empty' => false)); // show all tags, even empty 1s

// debug - uncomment below to view output
/* 
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($tags);
   echo "</pre>";
*/

if( is_array($tags) )
{
   foreach($tags as $tag):
    ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id);?>" class="badge badge-success">
         <?php echo $tag->name;?>
      </a>
   <?php 
   endforeach; 
}else{
  echo "<p>Not an Array!</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: `if( is_array() )`...assume you meant `if( is_array($tags) )`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't assume that a variable returned from a function will always be an array, you can check this before calling `foreach` like this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
if (is_array($tags) || is_object($tags)) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the specific case of `get_the_tags()`, this might be enough though:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        ...
    }
}
```